# Vaadin JPAContainer , Group By

Tags: vaadin, jpacontainer

i'm trying to create a query with JPAContainer on Vaadin, but i need to group by a couple of fields.

I haven't find any way to do that, is there someone who can help me?

Is FreeFormQuery and SQLContainer the only possible solution?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: JPA has no concept of GROUP BY, so JPAContainer too has no support for this. Why do you need it?

Comment: Because the only chance to solve the problem is via FreeFormQuery and SQLContainer, and that's not, in example, sortable in table.
It can be transformed in sortable table, but that's need an heavy work on FreeformStatementDelegate override... 

The need is to avoid all this work! :D

Comment: JPA is for Reading<->Writing Java objects to the persistence layer. It is definitively not intended to be used for reporting purposes... There "simple" SQL stamentes are much more powerfull and efficient, but they break the neat object model... :(